# Shockwave flash won't load URL

Tags: c#, flash, visual-studio-2008, url, axshockwaveflash

I have been using the flash object in visual studio 2008 to play `.swf` files and all was going well until `ustream.tv` videos suddenly stopped working overnight without having updated the code.  Was playing when I went to bed and wouldn't work again (on any computer) after I woke up (jan 15).

The [link](http://ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf?cid=12717079) that stopped working.

Other [links](http://cdn.livestream.com/grid/LSPlayer.swf?channel=newstalk) will still work fine but `ustream` will not work at all.  Every single link I was using is still working with the exception for any `ustream.tv` one.

I have tried using the program on other computers where it was previously installed and it's not working there either.  The ustream link still works in my browser and Flash Projector but that's not useful to me.

If I right click on the flash object on my form after the video is loaded there's a check next to Loop.  Pressing Play or any other option in that menu won't make it load.

The project is very simple so please test by placing flash object on form in visual studio and loading the above ustream link into it.

Thanks!

Comment: two thoughts:  If it was working before you went to bed, and is now not working (assuming no gremlins live in/near your house) then there's probably an issue with the ustream.tv site.  Otherwise, if you post some code, people can point out where the problems might lie.

Comment: I have also been considering that it was a change on the ustream site but I would like to know why the ustream links will work everywhere except the flash object in visual studio.  I never posted any code since it just requires a flash object on a form to test.